# @Autowired works but not @Inject

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, cdi

I have a Resource which injects the following class

```
@Component
public class CustomDozerBeanMapper implements Mapper {
    private final DozerBeanMapper beanMapper;

    public CustomDozerBeanMapper() {
        this.beanMapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
        BeanMappingBuilder builder = new BeanMappingBuilder() {
            protected void configure() {
                //some mapping stuff
            }
        };
        beanMapper.addMapping(builder);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T map(Object o, Class<T> aClass) throws MappingException {
        return beanMapper.map(o, aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void map(Object o, Object o1) throws MappingException {
        beanMapper.map(o, o1);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T map(Object o, Class<T> aClass, String s) throws MappingException {
        return beanMapper.map(o, aClass, s);
    }

    @Override
    public void map(Object o, Object o1, String s) throws MappingException {
        beanMapper.map(o, o1, s);
    }
}
```

In my applicationContext.xml I have declared

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar"/>
<bean id="customDozerMapper" class="foo.bar.CustomDozerBeanMapper" />
```

Then in our resource I inject it

```
class SomeResource {
   @Inject CustomDozerMapper customDozerMapper;

   //We have loads of other Injects which work just fine, only this class has problems
}
```

---

```
Caused by: A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=CustomDozerBeanMapper,parent=SomeResource,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1098507248)

    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:75)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:947)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:975)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:965)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider$SpringManagedBeanFactory.provide(SpringComponentProvider.java:191)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.FactoryCreator.create(FactoryCreator.java:153)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.PerLookupContext.findOrCreate(PerLookupContext.java:70)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:761)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:700)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
```

Now if I change and use @Autowired, it works fine
We are using Spring for dependency management, but for some reason h2k is being used, and I get the following exception

Can anyone please explain what the problem might be?

Why does it work with @Autowired and not @Inject

Why is h2k being used, and not Spring?

Comment: why did you define one bean 2 times (in the XML config and with `@Component`)?

Comment: No special reason. I can try to remove the annotation, and see if it helps

Comment: Wow, that actually solved it. Huge WTF moment for me. If that was a huge problem, it should have made a better error message

Comment: @AndrewTobilko if you post your comment as answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the problem may be because of 2 bean declarations (one in the XML configuration and the another one with `@Component`) and a DI container couldn't able to pick up one of them.

All solutions that are available here:

1. removing one of the bean definitions (I'd prefer the XML one)
2. specifying a bean by the `@Qualifier` or `@Named` annotation

Answer (score 0):

The problem might also be due to the bean name in config file `customDozerMapper` and actual injection `customerDozerMapper` are not matching. If `@inject` does not find matching bean, it throws an exception. However, there is provision for `@autowired` wherein you can set attribute `required=false` and it injects null if it does not find matching bean.

> Note: Configuration in config xml overrides the annotation
>   configuration.

Comment: Sorry this is not the problem. You are both right and wrong. It was a typo when I wrote `customerDozerMapper` here on stackoverflow. I fixed it. The problem was that I had defined @Component and the same bean in applicationContext.xml

Comment: Well defining @Component and same bean in config file should not be a problem. Config file simply overrides your annotation configuration. Just wondering how did it solve your problem. :-)

Comment: @Khuzi, XML doesn't override the annotation config in this case, just 2 beans with different names will be created

Comment: @Andrew So the 'different names' (at least one) is decided by Spring framework? and what could be those 2 names for example?

Comment: @sura2k, here, they should be `customDozerBeanMapper` (a name is not specified) and `customDozerMapper` (as the `id` value)

Comment: Ok....So using `@Qualifier` or `@Named` should work, if we go with the same configuration...